# .htaccess RewriteRule with an extra query string

Tags: .htaccess

I have changed the path of some of my urls, and I'd like to redirect them to some new urls with an extra query string `?industry=`

```
Old url: e.g. https://domain.ext/skills/keywords/list.php?q=account+manager
https://domain.ext/skills/keywords/list.php?q=assistant

New url: e.g.
https://domain.ext/skills/keywords/list.php?industry=human-resources&q=account+manager

https://domain.ext/skills/keywords/list.php?industry=banking&q=account+manager

https://domain.ext/skills/keywords/list.php?industry=banking&q=assistant
```

As you can see the new URls contains a new query parameter `industry=` which can have different industries. 
So how can I check if a new url exist with the query `?q=account+manager` for example and then redirect the old url to one of the new url that match `&q=account+manager`? 
I've looked into `RewriteRule` with `.htaccess`, but I haven't been able to find the right redirection yet. If someone could share some thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. How should an automatic process know what new and old URLs relate to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you wish to do, but I will take this question as a request for a simple example of a Rewrite Rule. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, several approaches may be used.

The code in the .htaccess file could be like this:

```
# essential
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Here a simple rule, the link ending with assitant will be sent to list.php as the q parameter
RewriteRule ^skills/keywords/assistant$ list.php?q=assistant
# You may use variables and Regex, such as $1, $2, $3 in this case to receive the values 
# in the parentheses for the three parameters
RewriteRule ^(en/fr/es)/(keywords)/([\/\.\w_-]{3,})$ list.php?lang=$1&section=$2&q=$3 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Flags are these ones:

- NC = No Case
- R=301 = returns a 301 (permanent redirection) code    rather than a
  302 (temporary) for SEO purposes
- L = Last ruel to be    executed,
  next ones are ignored.

I haven't check if this code works, when testing this on your server, you will encounter a blank page if something is wrong. Also, if you use flags, make sure there is no whitespace after the comma.

This page explains all this very well: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/rewrite/intro.html